# Getting the _id of the rows in ListVew right

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter, simpleadapter

I have a `ListView` which shows a bunsh of values from a SQLite table. First I used a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to fill the `ListView` based on a Cursor from an SQL query. I switched over to using a `SimpleAdapter` in stead because I had to manipulate/add data in the list before sending it over to the `ListView`.

Using the `SimpleCursorAdapter` the id returned from the `ListView` after tapping a row is the correct ID from the database table, but using a `SimpleAdapter` the id looks like its just generated by the `ListView` because it is the same as the position.

My table looks like this:

`_id | col1 | col2 | col3`

The method producing the cursor for the `SimpleCursorAdapter` looks like this:

```
public Cursor fetchDataAsCursor()
{
  return db.query("table_name", new String[] { "_id", "col1", "col2"}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

The method filling in the `ListView` using `SimpleCursorAdapter` looks like this:

```
  private void simpleFillData()
  {
    Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.fetchDataAsCursor();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[] {"col1", "col2"};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.col1, R.id.col2};

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.list_row, cursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
  }
```

This works fine as the id returned is ok in the following method:

```
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
  {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("_id", id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
  }
```

Now switching over to the `SimpleAdapter`.

The code for producing the `List`:

```
  public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getList()
  {
    ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList();

    c = fetchDataAsCursor();
    c.moveToFirst();
    for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++)
    {    
      HashMap<String, Object> h = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      h.put("_id", c.getLong(0));
      h.put("col1", c.getString(1));
      h.put("col2", c.getString(2));

      //This is the extra column
      h.put("extra", calculateSomeStuff(c.getString(1), c.getString(2));
      list.add(h);
      c.moveToNext();
    }

    return list;
  }
```

And then for the method which fills the `ListView`:

```
private void fillData()
  {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = dbAdapter.getList();
    String[] from = new String[] {"col1", "col2", "extra"};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.col1, R.id.col2, R.id.extra};
    SimpleAdapter notes = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.list_row, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
  }
```

In this last method the `ListView` failes to pick up the `_id` value in the list. I would have guessed that it would do this automaticly as it does when using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Is there a way to manipulate the id of a row in a `ListView` to be sure that it has the same value as the `_id` key in the database table?

(All code examples is greatly simplified)

***Edit:***

I figured it out. I had to make my own subclass of `SimpleAdapter` which overrides `public long getItemId(int position)`

```
public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleAdapter
{
  private final String ID = "_id";
  public PunchListAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
  {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position)
  {
    Object o = getItem(position);
    long id = position;
    if(o instanceof Map)
    {
      Map m = (Map)o;
      if(m.containsKey(ID))
      {
        o = m.get(ID);
        if(o instanceof Long)
          id = (Long)o;
      }
    } 
    return id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is bad way to work with cursor by using SimpleAdapter. You should implement CursorAdapter.

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
      LayoutInflater inflater;
      public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      }
```

```
 @Override
          public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            //cursor is already setted to requared position, just get your column
            TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            tv1.setText(cursor.getString(1));
            tv2.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            viev.addOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
                 public void onClick(View v){
                    ...
                    cursor.getLong(0);
                    ...
                 }
            });       
          }
```

```
@Override
      public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_raw_view, parent, false);
      }
    }
```

Than just set adapter to listview in your activity.

```
Cursor cursor = fetchDataAsCursor();
    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
    myListView.setAdapter(new MyCursorAdapter(this,cursot));
```